# how to get output by date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Newbie to sql:

I have the following query that results in an output that has the same date range in multiple rows. I'd like to merge those results into one single row. how can i do this?

```
SELECT (sum(likes + comments + video_views)/ sum(influencer_starting_followers)) as ER, Left(post_date,7) as Date 
from `public_sponsored_instagram_posts`
GROUP BY post_date
```

Chart output

| ER | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 0.04 | 2019-02 |
| 0.06 | 2019-02 |

DESIRED OUTPUT:

| ER | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 0.05 | 2019-02 |

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `date` column, then you should be getting an error in using string functions on it.

I would recommend:

```
SELECT date_trunc(post_date, month) as Date,
       (sum(likes + comments + video_views)/ sum(influencer_starting_followers)) as ER
FROM `public_sponsored_instagram_posts`
GROUP BY 1;
```

If your value is a string -- you should really fix that.  In the meantime, you can use either:

```
GROUP BY 2
```

or:

```
GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `GROUP BY post_date` with `GROUP BY 2`